# Mutiplication of matrices by multiplying blocks of entries.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

Let
$$\mathbf{A}= \begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} &  A_{12}&\dots  &A_{1r} \\ 
A_{21} &A_{22}  &\dots  &A_{2r} \\ 
\vdots  & \vdots &\ddots   &\vdots \\ 
A_{s1} &A_{s2}  &\dots  &A_{sr} 
\end{bmatrix}$$
be an $n\times m$ matrix on a ring. where the $A_{ij}$ are sub-matrices (rectangular blocks of entries).
Let
$$\mathbf{B}= \begin{bmatrix}
B_{11} &  B_{12}&\dots  &B_{1q} \\ 
B_{21} &B_{22}  &\dots  &B_{2q} \\ 
\vdots  & \vdots &\ddots   &\vdots \\ 
B_{r1} &B_{r2}  &\dots  &B_{rq} 
\end{bmatrix}$$
be a similar $m\times p$ matrix on the same ring.

Assuming
$$\sum_{k=1}^{r} \begin{bmatrix}
A_{1k}B_{k1} &  A_{1k}B_{k2}&\dots  &A_{1k}B_{kq} \\ 
A_{2k}B_{k1} &A_{2k}B_{k2}  &\dots  &A_{2k}B_{kq} \\ 
\vdots  & \vdots &\ddots   &\vdots \\ 
A_{sk}B_{k1} &A_{sk}B_{k2}  &\dots  &A_{sk}B_{kq} 
\end{bmatrix}$$
is a valid expression (including valid matrix mutiplications), is it equal to $\mathbf{AB}$?

---

As an [example](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Chuge%20%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D%20%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D*%5C%5C%20*%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D%20%26%20%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D%20*%20%26%20*%20%5C%5C%20*%20%26%20*%20%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D%20%5C%5C%20%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D%20*%20%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D%26%20%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D%20*%20%26%20*%20%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D%20%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D%20%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D%20%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D%20@%20%26%20@%20%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D%20%26%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D%20@%20%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D%20%5C%5C%20%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D%20@%20%26@%20%5C%5C%20@%20%26@%20%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D%20%26%20%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D%20@%5C%5C%20@%20%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D%20%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D) is this a valid mutiplication of $3\times 3$ matrices?:

[image]

[image]

Comment: in the image 3 by 3 mutiplication is reduced to a 2 by 2 mutiplication but now the entries are matrices. tex could not be rendered so I had to link an image.

Comment: the image is just to clarify the question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This follows from the definition of matrix multiplication. In fact, the subblocks don't need to be square. As long as they have conforming sizes, you can evaluate $AB$ blockwise.

Comment: by square I meant rectangular! However it does not seem to be trivial! do you have a referenece for a proof?

Comment: I don't have a reference, but essentially you just do something like this: $\sum_{t=1}^n a_{it}b_{tj}=\sum_{k=1}^r \sum_{s=1}^{|\mathcal{I}_k|} a_{is}b_{sj}$, where $\mathcal{I}_k$ is the column index set for the $k$-th column of subblocks of $A$ (i.e. the row index set for the $k$-th row of subblocks of $B$).